# Postfix isn't delivering Mails only to one specific user

Tags: debian, postfix, openldap, mailbox, cyrus

Our Mailsystem includes a Postfix, openLDAP and Cyrus. All run smoothly till last week. When I created a new Mailbox for a user who before had only an Alias with an forwarding external Mailadress. To this new Mailbox the Emails aren't delivered. Sending is ok.

First I thought about some caching problem, but it persists.

The Mails stuck in the Mailqueue of Postfix. In the logs I found this difference regarding a Mail which gets delivered and one to this user:

> root@server:/# grep 80D41241356 /var/log/mail.log
>   Apr 25 11:39:11 server postfix/smtpd[12439]: 80D41241356:
>   client=kes.domain.de[IP]
>   Apr 25 11:39:11 server postfix/cleanup[12442]: 80D41241356: message-id=<3808909c-c8fa-7d93-b2e4-a225ffa7a48b@domain.de>
>   Apr 25 11:39:11 server postfix/qmgr[12406]: 80D41241356: from=admin@domain.de, size=997, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>   Apr 25 11:39:11 server postfix/pipe[12445]: 80D41241356:
>   to=admin@domain.de, orig_to=admin@domain.de, relay=cyrus, delay=0.1,
>   delays=0/0.02/0/0.08, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via cyrus service)
>   Apr 25 11:39:11 server postfix/qmgr[12406]: 80D41241356: removed

this Mail remains in the Queue:

> root@server:/# grep 706AB240FC4 /var/log/mail.log
>   Apr 25 11:38:45 server postfix/smtpd[12439]: 706AB240FC4: client=kes.domain.de[IP]
>   Apr 25 11:38:45 server postfix/cleanup[12442]: 706AB240FC4: message-id=ff5eecc9-73a3-e605-1567-21c9814f3f4b@domain.de
>   Apr 25 11:38:45 server postfix/qmgr[12406]: 706AB240FC4:
>   from=, size=1006, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

I switched on the debuglevel and get:

> Apr 29 11:30:36 server postfix/local[15680]: deliver_dotforward[3]: set 
>   user_attr: mvogt
>   Apr 29 11:30:36 server postfix/local[15680]:
>   set_eugid: euid 3146 egid 2017

then it hangs in the queue. Thie following Mail is sent to another user, which has almost the same permissions and it is delivered in the cyrus Mailbox correctly. Here is the Logfile extract.

> Apr 29 11:28:57 server postfix/local[15680]: deliver_dotforward[3]: set
>   user_attr: atest
>   Apr 29 11:28:57 server postfix/local[15680]: set_eugid:
>   euid 3005 egid 2017
>   Apr 29 11:28:57 server postfix/local[15680]:
>   set_eugid: euid 110 egid 116
>   Apr 29 11:28:57 server
>   postfix/local[15680]: deliver_dotforward: path /home/atest/.forward
>   expand_status 0 look_status -1
>   Apr 29 11:28:57 server
>   postfix/local[15680]: deliver_mailbox[3]: local atest recip
>   atest@server.domain.de exten  deliver
>   atest@server.domain.de exp_from

I would be very happy if anyone can give me a hint what means set_eugid in this context. Looking in /etc/groups and /etc/passwd

> postfix:x:116:
>
> postfix:x:110:116:

maybe this is also the totally wrong conclusion and there is something else missing. If there is important information missing I can add them, just dont want to put all the configurations, because the Server is working ok.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How was the forwarding done previously? Has that been undone? How did you go from queue ID 80D41241356 to 706AB240FC4?

Comment: The Queue IDs are two different Mails, one went through for a user with the same permissions in the filesystem to compare the logs

Comment: The forwarding was done with ldapdirectory entry in aliases. This worked fine before. Yes it is undone.

Comment: @wurtel Any Idea how I could debug better? Which logs I could use additionally to putting -v in /etc/postfix/master.cf      #grep " -v" /etc/postfix/master.cf 
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup -v
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr -vv
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local -vv
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp -vv
cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe -vv

Comment: Sorry, no. My expertise lies with exim. I am wondering about "706AB240FC4: from=," that the from= is empty; with a null sender that should at least be "from=<>". The "set_eugid" is postfix switching effective UID and GID to first the user's ID (to read his .forward file) and then back again.

Comment: arrgh, no the from is not empty, was dealing a lot with the quote format here, it swallowed all between <>, will correct that. Thanks anyway!